# SQL Query performance that use subquery and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to speed execution time for the following query as it take too long time to execute and i think the sub query is the problem

```
SELECT WFApplication.*,
       WorkflowIncidentType.TypeName ProcessCategory,
       WFProcess.WFProcessName ProcessName,
       LUTAppStatus.EnglishName AppStatus
FROM WFApplication
INNER JOIN LUTAppStatus ON WFApplication.ApplicationStatus = LUTAppStatus.Id
INNER JOIN WorkflowIncidentType ON WorkflowIncidentType.TypeID = WFApplication.ApplicationIncidentType
INNER JOIN WFProcess ON WFProcess.WFProcessId = WFApplication.ApplicationProcess
LEFT OUTER JOIN IBSCustomer ON IBSCustomer.RIM = WFApplication.RIM
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reschedule ON Reschedule.RescheduleId = WFApplication.ProcessId
WHERE WFApplication.ProcessId IN
    (SELECT ProcessId
     FROM WFProcessInstanceLog)
  AND WFProcessInstanceId IN (28251,
                              28345,
                              28773,
                              28774,
                              28846,
                              29309, .....)
```

Comment: You may be correct, but the execution plan would tell you for sure. Could you paste it here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: How can i get it as i have no great experience in sql ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The subquery is pretty much the same as an extra `INNER JOIN`, it just checks that a column is contained in another table. With the proper indexes that's unlikely to create trouble.

Comment: However, the large `IN` list of numbers could be the culprit. How many values are you sending there?

Comment: there is around 5000 number

Comment: improvement: SELECT WFApplication.*,
       WorkflowIncidentType.TypeName ProcessCategory,
       WFProcess.WFProcessName ProcessName,
       LUTAppStatus.EnglishName AppStatus

FROM (SELECT ProcessId pid FROM WFProcessInstanceLog WHERE WFProcessInstanceId IN (28251,28345,28773,28774,28846,29309))pil
INNER JOIN WFApplication ON WFApplication.ProcessId = pil.pid ...LEFT OUTER JOIN Reschedule ON Reschedule.RescheduleId = WFApplication.ProcessId (WHERE REMOVED)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the basics of SQL Performance Optimizing for queries.

First step: Display the Actual Execution Plan.  In the 'Query' menu, check 'Include Actual Execution Plan'.  Then, when you run the query, an extra tab will appear in the results pane, for 'Execution Plan'.

Second Step: Look at the right-most nodes in the tree.  There will generally be four possibilities:

- **Table Scan.**  Basically, this is bad.  It's indicating that the full table had to be looked through to find what it was looking for - no indexes used at all.  If the table is small, that might not matter much; if the table is large, you've probably got a problem.
- **Clustered Index Scan.**  Also bad.  Clustered Indexes *are* the table, so if SQL is scanning through one, it means its scanning through the whole table.
- **Index Scan - Nonclustered.**  Semi-bad.  Basically, it *was* able to use an index to help look through the data (better than a full table) but it wasn't able to use Binary Finds to quickly narrow down the data it was looking for.
- **Index Seek (either Nonclustered or Clustered)** - What you're after.  This means SQL was able to binary-find its way quickly to the data its looking for.

Now, what causes SQL to choose one option over another?  The first big thing is your indexes.  Often, the 'Execution Plan' will alert you to missing indexes that'd improve the performance of your query.  But you can manually look - if it's going through "Table A" using a full scan... why?  What column is it looking up, searching on, or matching against?  Chances are, that column needs to have an index so the engine can quickly match against it.

But there are other reasons.  Lets say the table isn't that big, and you're matching lots of entries against the table.  It might be faster for SQL to just look through the whole table.

Another reason that's often overlooked: you've got indexes on the relevant columns, but they don't narrow down the data enough to make them worthwhile - or, alternatively, it's looking through so many different indexes that trying to wrangle them all up against the original table is slower than just using the large table.  If this is the case, the solution is to create indexes with multiple columns in the index.

One good way to diagnose a problem like this is to omit some of the tables/data and see if the execution plan changes.  For example, try this query out:

```
SELECT WFApplication.*
FROM WFApplication
WHERE WFProcessInstanceId IN (28251,
                          28345,
                          28773,
                          28774,
                          28846,
                          29309, .....)
```

Does the execution plan change?  If the plan in the above statement is bad, it probably means that you're missing an index on WFProcessInstanceId or that your table isn't big enough to justify 5000 references against the main table.

But if it uses an Index Seek on that query, but *switches* to a Scan op when you add other tables, it might be a sign that you need to add those additional lookup columns to a separate index, so that it doesn't have to try to coordinate multiple indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the subquery you could instead do an inner join between wfapplication and wfprocessingstancelog.There isn't a good reason to use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT WFApplication.*,
       WorkflowIncidentType.TypeName ProcessCategory,
       WFProcess.WFProcessName ProcessName,
       LUTAppStatus.EnglishName AppStatus
FROM WFApplication
Inner Join WFProcessInstanceLog WPL on WPL.ProcessID = WFApplicaiton.ProcessId
INNER JOIN LUTAppStatus ON WFApplication.ApplicationStatus = LUTAppStatus.Id
INNER JOIN WorkflowIncidentType ON WorkflowIncidentType.TypeID = WFApplication.ApplicationIncidentType
INNER JOIN WFProcess ON WFProcess.WFProcessId = WFApplication.ApplicationProcess
LEFT OUTER JOIN IBSCustomer ON IBSCustomer.RIM = WFApplication.RIM
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reschedule ON Reschedule.RescheduleId = WFApplication.ProcessId
WHERE WFProcessInstanceId IN (28251,
                              28345,
                              28773,
                              28774,
                              28846,
                              29309, .....)
```

Comment: Great, what is the good query if i need to use NOT IN before subquery instead of IN ?

Comment: Literally use `NOT IN` instead of `IN`, just as you stated @Moustafa

Comment: this takes also too long time do you have any other solution ?